# Which IDE is the best in terms of generating gui codes? JBuilder or Netbeans?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, jbuilder

which of these great IDEs?

Answer (score 1):

**Netbeans** rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is awesome. It rocks. Be it for mobile or desktop, it has a great intelligence and power. Netbeans rocks.